# Terraform plan fails when applying on GCP resources

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, google-kubernetes-engine

I have used following terraform plan command but it fails.

```
./terraform plan -out "infraplan"
```

> Error: Missing newline after argument  on terraform.tfvars line 2: region=$region

My tfvars file the line is:

```
region=$region
gke-cluster-name=$cluster_name
subnet-range=$subnets_primary
pod-ip-range=$pod_ips
```

Any help?

Comment: You can't use interpolation in tfvars files. If you want to use environment variables then you'll need to either export them as `TF_VAR_variable_name=value` or use `-var variable_name=value` on the command line instead of using tfvars files.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Can you try put these variables in the quoted strings? I have faced same issue. Hope this helps.

It can't identify the value if you don't mention it as a string.

Comment: This isn't the issue. They are attempting to use expressions in a tfvars file which isn't supported.

Comment: It worked, I used it in my gitlab pipeline and after putting it inside the string it works fine. Thanks,